Page_author is not appear in GA4 DebugView
How should I track the page author traffic from my website to GA?
I cant find page_author in my GA debugview
I already add parameter in my main tag in GTM
And this is the variable that I am using
[When I access the variable in messages, there you have it (the pagePostAuthor] https://i.sstatic.net/BOls0vkz.png
[But the value is undefined in the container load] https://i.sstatic.net/CbZvDgOr.png
I hope to see page_author (or anything else similar) to show me the traffic that is coming to my website based on the author.

So the problem is the dataLayer push snippet is behind or after the GTM snippet.
Here are several ways to solve it.

Try to put the dataLayer snippet before the GTM snippet.

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({...})

<script>(function(){ //GTM Snippet })()</script>


Add an event name for the dataLayer push and set another corresponding trigger.

Use Dom Ready or Window Loaded trigger but it's not very ideal since you might lose some data.


